# drupal user names and url

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How **special characters** in username converted to user path (*users/username*). i'm asking because when i use "." in user name its removed in user path.
 for ex: stefan.z path will be users/stefanz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Drupal don't do this, it uses the user's id instead.

Most likely you are using path auto to do this, which can hook into the translitation module. It also has some of it's own functions, that is uses to clean up the url generated.

Answer (score 2):

Special characters are not allowed like that generally- but if you use the Pathauto module, you can change the vanity URL of user paths and also tell Pathauto what characters are allowed and what isn't.